# How to repair water damage on a wall

Tags: water-damage

We are trying to repair the water damage on a wall and we cleaned it up pretty good and sealed the exterior to prevent water from re-entering.

My question is: What should we use to fill the gap in between the window and the wall?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space between the window and wall I'd just stuff with some fiberglass insulation. I wouldn't be using the expanding foam because it might put a strain on the window and impede operation. Then straighten out that drywall edge and add a new piece down to the window and tape with mud. If the space is small enough, cover with some trim or molding. The latter will look weird if the other windows don't have the same molding.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help